# Cannot group by with table with same column name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `swp`.`competition_seasons` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `competition_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `season_id` INT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `update_at` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `swp`.`competition` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `country_id` INT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `category` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `id_idx` (`country_id` ASC)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

so I want select all the competition available, but the problem's that each competition have different seasons, so in the final result I'll get something like:

```
{
    "id": "1093",
    "country_id": "1",
    "category": "1",
    "competition_name": "Premier League",
    "season_name": "2018",
    "season_id": "2",
},
{
    "id": "1093",
    "country_id": "1",
    "category": "1",
    "competition_name": "Premier League",
    "season_name": "2017"
    "season_id": "3",
}
```

I want return a single result that contains something like:

```
   {
    "id": "1093",
    "country_id": "1",
    "category": "1",
    "competition_name": "Premier League",
    "seasons": [
                  ["season_name":"2018", "season_id":"2"],
                  ["season_name":"2017", "season_id":"3"],
               ] 
   }
```

what I did so far:

```
SELECT
    c.id, c.country_id, c.category,
    c.name AS competition_name, s.name AS season_name
  FROM competition c
  LEFT JOIN competition_seasons s ON c.id = s.competition_id
  WHERE country_id = :country_id
  GROUP BY c.name, c.id
```

this will return:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #5 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'swp.s.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: You can't select column values which aren't contained in your group by clause unless they are part of an Aggregate function like COUNT or SUM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT c.id, c.country_id, c.category, c.name AS competition_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(s.name ORDER BY s.name) AS season_names
FROM competition c LEFT JOIN
     competition_seasons s
     ON c.id = s.competition_id
WHERE country_id = :country_id
GROUP BY c.id, c.country_id, c.category, c.name;
```

EDIT:

You can't exactly return arrays of structs in MySQL.  You can format the string:

```
       GROUP_CONCAT(s.name, ':', s.id ORDER BY s.name) AS season_names
```

Note that `GROUP_CONCAT()` takes multiple arguments and concatenates them together.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your answer, this will fix the problem I have, how can I return the season also with id in array as I wrote? Actually I get: `"season_names": "2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018"`

Answer (score 0):

When you group rows, all columns not participating in the group condition should be aggregated by any aggregation function. You can use `min()`, `max()`, `avg()`, etc. Only grouping columns can appear as plain columns.

You query should look similar to:

```
SELECT
    c.id, 
    c.name AS competition_name, 
    max(c.country_id), 
    max(c.category),
    max(s.name) AS season_name
  FROM competition c
  LEFT JOIN competition_seasons s ON c.id = s.competition_id
  WHERE country_id = :country_id
  GROUP BY c.name, c.id
```